# Guess the number with React - what is the proper way of using state in that case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React client app should guess the secret number between 1 and 10 000. Here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GuessEngine extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      number: null,
      result: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const firstGuess = 5000;
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
        isNumber: firstGuess,
      })
      .then(response => {
        const { resultCode } = response.data;
        this.setState({ number: firstGuess });
        this.setState({ result: resultCode });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    if (prevState !== this.state) {
      if (this.state.result === 'lower') {
        const newNumber = this.state.number - 1;
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
          isNumber: newNumber,
        });
        this.setState({ number: newNumber });
      }

      if (this.state.result === 'higher') {
        const newNumber = this.state.number + 1;
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
          isNumber: newNumber,
        });
        this.setState({ number: newNumber });
      }

      if (this.state.result === 'success') {
        console.log(`Success! The secret number is ${this.state.number}!`);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}

export default GuessEngine;
```

And I'm getting an error like this:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

So if I can't use `componentDidUpdate` like this, what is the proper way to use `React Lifecycle Hooks` to make it work?

My app has sent 1011 request and than it crashed.

---

### SOLUTION

So using @John_Ruddell answer I came up with this solution:

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.result !== 'success') {
      if (this.state.result === 'lower') {
        const newNumber = this.state.number - 1;
        axios
          .post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
            isNumber: newNumber,
          })
          .then(response => {
            const { resultCode } = response.data;
            this.setState({ result: resultCode, number: newNumber });
          });
      } else if (this.state.result === 'higher') {
        const newNumber = this.state.number + 1;
        axios
          .post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
            isNumber: newNumber,
          })
          .then(response => {
            const { resultCode } = response.data;
            this.setState({ result: resultCode, number: newNumber });
          });
      }
    } else if (this.state.result === 'success') {
      console.log(`Success! The secret number is ${this.state.number}!`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Sorry! Some errors occured!`);
    }
  }
```

This code does not compares `this.state.number !== prevState.number`, but only in this way I forced it to work

Comment: `setState` triggers an update, so put it anywhere else except where it mentions in the error.

Comment: @jmargolisvt, but I need to test multiple cases, so it should do another test after taking for consideration changes in state. Do you have an idea where else I can put it?

Comment: @jmargolisvt thats not true.. setState can and probably should be in the did update to change data.. you just have to be smart about how you call it... for instance in his answer he is always setting state, and not waiting for the request callback.. meaning he never changes his result to be success when he guesses the right number.. if you wait for the request callback to setState it would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting state every time the component did update is firing.. instead of waiting for a callback from the request to see if its lower or higher

also you should put the logic of state transitions into better conditionals

```
const nextNum = { lower: -1, higher: 1 } // simple mapping of the next guess so you can reduce amount of code
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.result && this.state.number !== prevState.number) {
        if (nextNum[this.state.result]) {
            // make request with the number
             const newNumber = nextNum[this.state.result]
             axios.post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
                 isNumber: newNumber,
             }).then(response => {
                 const { resultCode } = response.data;
                 this.setState({result: resultCode, number: newNumber})
             }).catch(error => console.log(error));
        } else if (this.state.result === 'success') {
            console.log(`Success! The secret number is ${this.state.number}!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the key thing here is you should only setState **AFTER** the request comes back.. or else you will just endlessly setState.. because `this.state.result` will never be updated to be success

Comment: Did you mean `if (this.state.result && this.state.number !== prevState.number)` ? Beacuse this.state.result can be the same for 4000 guesses, it simply respond 'lower' or 'higher'

Answer (score 1):

`setState` will lead to the update so your `componentDidUpdate` will be called over and over again:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
  // after each update this will be true and further runing another updates
  if (prevState !== this.state) {  
  }
}
```

You need better logic to decipher whether you need to do an update or not. Meaning at some point `componentDidUpdate` should not do anything.